# Check for every rugby score the recursive way without repetitions

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

Just for fun I created an algorithm that computes every possible combination from a given rugby score (3, 5 or 7 points). I found two methods : The first one is brute force, 3 imbricated `for` loops. The other one is recursion.

Problem is some combinations appear multiple times. How can I avoid that ?

My code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void computeScore( int score, int nbTryC, int nbTryNC, int nbPenalties );

int main()
{
    int score = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Enter score : ";
        cin >> score;
        cout << "---------------" << endl << "SCORE = " << score << endl
                << "---------------" << endl;

        // Recursive call
        computeScore(score, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}

void computeScore( int score, int nbTryC, int nbTryNC, int nbPenalties )
{
    const int tryC = 7;
    const int tryNC = 5;
    const int penalty = 3;

    if (score == 0)
    {
        cout << "* Tries: " << nbTryC << " | Tries NT: " << nbTryNC
                << " | Penal/Drops: " << nbPenalties << endl;
        cout << "---------------" << endl;
    }
    else if (score < penalty)
    {
        // Invalid combination
    }
    else
    {
        computeScore(score - tryC, nbTryC+1, nbTryNC, nbPenalties);
        computeScore(score - tryNC, nbTryC, nbTryNC+1, nbPenalties);
        computeScore(score - penalty, nbTryC, nbTryNC, nbPenalties+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: the usual way of avoiding duplicates for something like this would be to sort them (`std::sort`) before printing them and then duplicates would be next to each other, which would allow you to decide how to handle them.

Comment: in a language that supports such things you could pass through a set that accumulates the values and detects/rejects tuples.

Comment: Thanks guys, but I would like to be language independant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to think about this is to realize that any time you have a sum, you can put it into some "canonical" form by sorting all the values.  For example, given

```
20 = 5 + 7 + 3 + 5
```

You could also write this as

```
20 = 7 + 5 + 5 + 3
```

This gives a few different options for how to solve your problem.  First, you could always sort and record all of the sums that you make, never outputting the same sum twice.  This has the problem that you're going to end up repeatedly generating the same sums multiple different times, which is extremely inefficient.

The other (and much better) way to do this is to update the recursion to work in a slightly different way.  Right now, your recursion works by always adding 3, 5, and 7 at each step.  This is what gets everything out of order in the first place.  An alternative approach would be to think about adding in all the 7s you're going to add, then all the 5's, then all the 3's.  In other words, your recursion would work something like this:

```
 Let kValues = {7, 5, 3}

 function RecursivelyMakeTarget(target, values, index) {
      // Here, target is the target to make, values are the number of 7's,
      // 5's, and 3's you've used, and index is the index of the number you're
      // allowed to add.

      // Base case: If we overshot the target, we're done.
      if (target < 0) return;

      // Base case: If we've used each number but didn't make it, we're done.
      if (index == length(kValues)) return;

      // Base case: If we made the target, we're done.
      if (target == 0) print values; return;

      // Otherwise, we have two options:
      // 1. Add the current number into the target.
      // 2. Say that we're done using the current number.

      // Case one
      values[index]++;
      RecursivelyMakeTarget(target - kValues[index], values, index);
      values[index]--;

      // Case two
      RecursivelyMakeTarget(target, values, index + 1);
 }

 function MakeTarget(target) {
      RecursivelyMakeTarget(target, [0, 0, 0], 0);
 }
```

The idea here is to add in all of the 7's you're going to use before you add in any 5's, and to add in any 5's before you add in any 3's.  If you look at the shape of the recursion tree that's made this way, you will find that no two paths end up trying out the same sum, because when the path branches either a different number was added in or the recursion chose to start using the next number in the series.  Consequently, each sum is generated exactly once, and no duplicates will be used.

Moreover, this above approach scales to work with any number of possible values to add, so if rugby introduces a new SUPER GOAL that's worth 15 points, you could just update the `kValues` array and everything would work out just fine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's exactly the tree I was looking for. I had the idea but never would have thought of this implementation. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Each time you find a solution you could store it in a dictionary  ( a set of strings for example, with strings looking like "TC-TNT-P" )

Before printing a solution you verify it was not in the dictionary.

Comment: Probably an hash table would be better

Comment: @BlackBear - a `std::set` would be even better.

Comment: This works, but it's really inefficient; it generates the same scores multiple different ways, and for large numbers might not terminate within any reasonable time bounds.

Comment: @templatetypedef - perfomance wise using hash table is faster than the set ( o(log(n)) vs o(1) for each solution ). Note that the dictionary search is done only for solutions, not for every node in the tree. Then the algorithm itself could be enhanced by using an other dictionary to avoid scanning "equivalent" nodes in the tree, and as byresult this would also eliminate duplicates. But the question was about duplicates only, not performance.

Answer (score -4):

A nested for-loop is the natural way to do this. Using recursion is just silly (as you seem to have discovered).

Comment: While nested for loops work, they do not scale to handle the case where there are more than three (or more specifically, more than some fixed number) of different values that can be added in.  (And no, I didn't downvote).

Comment: But even the OP's recursive code restricts itself to three different values. So your comment is correct, but irrelevant.

Comment: @Isaac: I wasn't allowed to call your comment stupid (my comment was deleted), so I'm just going to have to call it silly.